# Error on copying subversion folder to another repository

Tags: svn

I have Project A checked into one subversion repository.

I have Project B checked into a different repository.

Not thinking, I copied several subdirectories on my local machine from Project A to Project B (some image/css/js directories).  I work on Mac OSX and the copy included the hidden subversion files.

Now when I checkin my entire Project B I get prompted for the login information for Project A.  The login always fails (since it's a different repository).  I've tried a cleanup but that didn't help.  I can't checkout a clean copy of Project B because I had files in it that weren't checked in prior to copying the new subfolders.

What are my options to fix the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Subversion stores its information is `.svn` directories. In pre-1.7, these were in each folder. In 1.7 and above, they are in the root folder.  Once all the `.svn` files are deleted, the folder will contain absolutely no Subversion information. However, these `.svn` folders tend to be invisible in the Finder.

If you want to see the `.svn` folders in Finder, open the Terminal app, and type in the following commands:

```
$ defaults write com.apple.finder AppleShowAllFiles TRUE
$ killall Finder
```

This will restart Finder, and show you the `.svn` files.

If you are familiar with the command line, you can use the `find` command to find the folders and delete them:

```
$ find . -name ".svn" -type d -exec rm -rf {} \;
```

If you don't know Unix and BASH, you should get a good book on Unix command line commands and BASH. The Mac is a true Unix system and has all of the power of Unix. If you install the Command Line Utilities, you will get all of the most popular open source tools. I also recommend learning [VIM](http://vim.org). It's a bit archaic, but is probably the most powerful programming editor out there. And, it's a standard editor on Linux, Unix, and Mac.

- [Learning the bash Shell 3rd edition](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596009656.do)
- [Learning Unix for OS X](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920025870.do)
- [Learning the VI and VIM Editors 7th Edition](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596529833.do). This will put hair on your chest.